# Automatically Choose Create/Update Query on AWS AppSync in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync, aws-appsync-ios

The user can create and edit his profile with `TextFields`:

- Username
- Nickname
- Biography

When the user presses the "Save" button, the app saves this data on **AWS AppSync**. If this is the first time the user enters this data the app should call `createData()`, otherwise it should call `updateData()`.

Currently I choose between the two methods manually while testing the app. Is there a way to do this automatically? and let the app know if this row of the dynamoDB table has been already created or not?

```
    @IBAction func saveBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        //How to choose automatically between these two methods?

        createData()
        // updateData()
    }

    func createData() {

        appSyncClient?.perform(mutation: CreateUserMutation(input: createQuery)) {

    }

    func updateData() {

        appSyncClient?.perform(mutation: UpdateUserMutation(input: updateQuery))

    }
```

This data is optional so I don't force the user to fill it when the account is being created. For authentication I am using Amazon Cognito Hosted UI. .